# Script to list the working directory of a vm

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to get a working directory of a running vms. I can do that in multiple bash command but I'm trying to do that in a one-liner.

Here's what I have got so far.

```
VBoxManage list runningvms | grep vip-quickstart | VBoxManage showvminfo $(awk -F '' '{print $1}')
```

But I get this error

> awk: field separator FS is empty

How do I pass the result of grep to VBoxManage command?

Here's the result of

VBoxManage list runningvms

```
"vip-quickstart_default_1431403025707_81359" {7b9a9c04-2bd9-4fd3-92c8-50293fbbca23}

"Some other running vms" {7b9a9c04-2bd9-4fd3-92c8-50293fbbca23}
```

And after I pipe that through `grep` I get this

```
"vip-quickstart_default_1431403025707_81359" {7b9a9c04-2bd9-4fd3-92c8-50293fbbca23}
```

And I thought I could awk that to get the VMId by `awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'` which I would get `"vip-quickstart_default_1431403025707_81359"` which I could pipe that again to

`VboxManage showvminfo`

How do I do that in a single command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is you have given '' blank in your first command. Giving blank as a field separator is a problem. If space is field separator then even if you don't mention -F' ' ,awk will work. for example

```
VBoxManage list runningvms | grep vip-quickstart | VBoxManage showvminfo $(awk  '{print $1}')
```

Now you want to run command VBoxManage showvminfo on the output from awk then use below:-

```
VBoxManage list runningvms | grep vip-quickstart | awk  '{print $1}' | xargs VBoxManage showvminfo
```

OR

```
VBoxManage list runningvms | awk '/vip-quickstart/{print $1}' | xargs VBoxManage showvminfo
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a type with field seperator where you dont have space after two quotes after `-F` argument.

Try something like:

```
VBoxManage list runningvms | awk '/vip-quickstart/{print $0}'
```